# Copy and Pasting Data based on Cell Input

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to copy and paste Rows from an original sheet (Ticket Sales) to a new Sheet (Rachel) based on the value in a specific Column for each Row (Column U). I want all the sales from Rachel to be copied over to another sheet, pretty much. No change in the formatting for the second sheet. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub CopyRachelDataPaste()    
    Dim i, LastRow

    'Get Last Row
    LasRow = Sheets("Ticket Sales").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Clear Contents
    Sheets("Rachel").Range("A2:AB3000").ClearContents

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Sheets("Ticket Sales").Cells(i, "U").Value = "Rachel" Then 
            Sheets("Ticket Sales").Cells(i, "U").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Rachel").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)    
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You have a typo: `LasRow = Sheets("Ticket Sales"). ...` should be `LastRow = Sheets("Ticket Sales"). ...`.  (Using option Explicit would detect these for you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must properly reference worksheet in all range definitions

like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRachelDataPaste()
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long

    Worksheets("Rachel").Range("A2:AB3000").ClearContents 'Clear Contents
    With Worksheets("Ticket Sales") '<--| reference ticket worksheet
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<--| get referenced worksheet column "A" last non empty row    
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If .Cells(i, "U").Value = "Rachel" Then .Cells(i, "U").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Rachel").Range("A" & Worksheets("Rachel").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works great. Also, what if I want to copy and past only a certain number of columns in a row and not EntireRow? For instance Columns A through V in Row i

Comment: You are welcome. Since I fulfilled your _original_ question, please mark answer as accepted. Thank you. Then, as per this site rules, you must make a new post for a new issue.